# Use I18n with active admin in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, activeadmin

I want to have custom menu and index title text based on I18n,
I am trying to do the following

```
menu label: I18t('admin.header')
index title: 'I18t('admin.header') do
```

But I am getting an error

```
undefined method `I18t' for #<ActiveAdmin::ResourceDSL
```

Comment: Could you try t("admin.header") and let me know if it works ?

Comment: No this not working either undefined method `t' for #<ActiveAdmin::ResourceDSL:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
I18n.t('admin.header')
```

Cheers :-)